# Swift hyperlink with UILabel

Tags: swift, hyperlink, uilabel

[image]

I like to ask if we can do hyperlink with UILabel, I know that we can do it with TextView. But my situation is that I have UILabel and I need to click on a specific text to go to another page or a website. I have looked around but most of solutions are making the whole UILabel clickable. Image above is an example. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: https://medium.com/swlh/clickable-link-on-a-swift-label-or-textview-98bbb067451d

Comment: You may also wish to review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uilabel+link).